# problems understanding nth-of-type selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I'm struggling on something I've never found that difficult :S so I have objects with the class .everyDay (are every cell for each day of the month), I have to differentiate those objects being: 5 green 3 red consecutively, but starting on the 3rd element. So the first two must be red.

Well, I've though I could do it easily with jQuery:

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("td.everyDay:nth(0), td.everyDay:nth(1)").css({"background-color": "red", "color" : "white"});
    $("td.everyDay:nth-of-type(4n+4), td.everyDay:nth-of-type(5n+5)").css({"background-color": "green", "color" : "white"});

});

And no way I get this working! I have tried all the existing numbers! -___- and I have look for how it works, but it is not 100% clear and maybe it is even less clear than I though... Anyone knows how to use this and can explain it to me?

Cheers!

UPDATE:

It is closer to what I need, however, it is not right as it doesn't follow 5 red 3 green for the whole year (starting on the 3rd element):

[image]

So if anyone can still explain me how nth-child and the numbers within parenthesis work... better! I don't want the solution, I want to get it myself but understanding what I'm doing :S thank you for helping!

And page source:

### From the browser console

```
<table class="t"><tbody><tr><th>2016</th><th>Dl</th><th>Dt</th><th>Dc</th><th>Dj</th><th>Dv</th><th>Ds</th><th>Dg</th><th>Dl</th><th>Dt</th><th>Dc</th><th>Dj</th><th>Dv</th><th>Ds</th><th>Dg</th><th>Dl</th><th>Dt</th><th>Dc</th><th>Dj</th><th>Dv</th><th>Ds</th><th>Dg</th><th>Dl</th><th>Dt</th><th>Dc</th><th>Dj</th><th>Dv</th><th>Ds</th><th>Dg</th><th>Dl</th><th>Dt</th><th>Dc</th><th>Dj</th><th>Dv</th><th>Ds</th><th>Dg</th><th>Dl</th><th>Dt</th></tr><tr><td>Gener</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="cadaDia">31</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Febrer</td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Març</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="cadaDia">31</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Abril</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Maig</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="cadaDia">31</td></tr><tr><td>Juny</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Juliol</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="cadaDia">31</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Agost</td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="cadaDia">31</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Setembre</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Octubre</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="cadaDia">31</td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Novembre</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr><tr><td>Decembre</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="cadaDia">1</td><td class="cadaDia">2</td><td class="cadaDia">3</td><td class="cadaDia">4</td><td class="cadaDia">5</td><td class="cadaDia">6</td><td class="cadaDia">7</td><td class="cadaDia">8</td><td class="cadaDia">9</td><td class="cadaDia">10</td><td class="cadaDia">11</td><td class="cadaDia">12</td><td class="cadaDia">13</td><td class="cadaDia">14</td><td class="cadaDia">15</td><td class="cadaDia">16</td><td class="cadaDia">17</td><td class="cadaDia">18</td><td class="cadaDia">19</td><td class="cadaDia">20</td><td class="cadaDia">21</td><td class="cadaDia">22</td><td class="cadaDia">23</td><td class="cadaDia">24</td><td class="cadaDia">25</td><td class="cadaDia">26</td><td class="cadaDia">27</td><td class="cadaDia">28</td><td class="cadaDia">29</td><td class="cadaDia">30</td><td class="cadaDia">31</td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td><td class="blank"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `:nth` selector, it's either `:nth-child()` of `:nth-of-type()` ?

Comment: Why not just use CSS?

Comment: You can learn how numbers works and try to test with **nth Tester** of css-tricks: https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/ it's useful to know how css functions works

Comment: The `:nth-of-type` will not respect the class selector.. it just goes by the element selector

Comment: what is your objective?

Comment: The use of this selectors in jQuery it's the same that the use of this selectors in CSS. This is not the problem. OP said `5 green 3 red consecutively, but starting on the 3rd element.`

Comment: share your html sample and what you really want to do

Comment: As i understand it, you want something like that (using CSS): http://jsfiddle.net/45fbw4xf/2/

Comment: yes A.Wolff that was what I was trying to do!!

Thank you!!!!! Can you explain it a bit? I can't catch were are the numbers coming from!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) is explaination regarding `nth-child(an+b)` expression, i don't think you can get clearer DOC

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS solution to get:

> 5 green 3 red consecutively, but starting on the 3rd element

```css
.everyDay:nth-child(1n+3) {
    background-color: green;
}

.everyDay, .everyDay:nth-child(8n), .everyDay:nth-child(8n+9), .everyDay:nth-child(8n+10) {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="everyDay">1</div>
<div class="everyDay">2</div>
<div class="everyDay">3</div>
<div class="everyDay">4</div>
<div class="everyDay">5</div>
<div class="everyDay">6</div>
<div class="everyDay">7</div>
<div class="everyDay">8</div>
<div class="everyDay">9</div>
<div class="everyDay">10</div>
<div class="everyDay">11</div>
<div class="everyDay">12</div>
<div class="everyDay">13</div>
<div class="everyDay">14</div>
<div class="everyDay">15</div>
<div class="everyDay">16</div>
<div class="everyDay">17</div>
<div class="everyDay">18</div>
<div class="everyDay">19</div>
<div class="everyDay">20</div>
<div class="everyDay">21</div>
<div class="everyDay">22</div>
<div class="everyDay">23</div>
<div class="everyDay">24</div>
<div class="everyDay">25</div>
<div class="everyDay">26</div>
<div class="everyDay">27</div>
<div class="everyDay">28</div>
<div class="everyDay">29</div>
<div class="everyDay">30</div>
<div class="everyDay">31</div>
```

```
:nth-child(1n+3)
```

Select all children starting at `3`

```
:nth-child(8n)
```

override previous CSS rule selecting all `8`nth (5+3) elements starting at `8`, and so on to get the `9, 10` elements selected using `:nth-child(8n+9)` & `:nth-child(8n+10)`

Comment: ouX..... does it is because my everyDay class is on <td> not between divs? Because it works here, but if I change your divs for td it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @eve_mf You have to share your relevant HTML markup

Comment: A. Wolff, I think my markup is not going to get any better putting it here, because the whole calendar is generated with php, so it is not a clean html markup, plus, I am not allowed to publish any content of work....  Anyway I've seen you are using nth-child, and I was using nth-of-type (I've though I was refering to the class with that one), so I will play for a while with the code you have put to try to understand it.

Thank you!

Comment: @eve_mf I guess because ya, you aren't sharing minimalistic sample to replicate issue and not clear enough regarding expected output BUT i'm not in other people mind, you know... Now, regarding your HTML markup, you can still provide the one rendered in browser regarding your table (not PHP one) and CSS rules you are using, so your issue would be clearer to catch. You want the `nth-child` depending each row, is it? Here an example using a table and works as expected (still as i understand it): http://jsfiddle.net/45fbw4xf/4/   So without seeing what you are doing, i cannot really help you more

Comment: @eve_mf PHP is server side code, it doesn't be processed client side. If you inspect the calendar you are using client side (in browser once rendered), you'll get the rendered HTML markup. This is this 'code' i was asking for (not the PHP server side one which you shouldn't share btw regarding `I am not allowed to publish any content of work` ). I'm really not sure why in your case `:nth-child` wouldn't work. I guess you are setting it to wrong level element

Comment: aaah do you mean to share the "view page source" then?

Comment: @eve_mf Ya, but just the relevant part regarding table and CSS rules (and sorry if my english isn't that good...)

Comment: I'm just messing my head up more every time I try to understand something --__-- the client wants the year calendar for 2016, the 1st and 2nd of january, he works, but from there, he does 5 days off, and 3 working, 5 days off, and 3 working until the end of december. And if I don't "paint" with each color each day I don't know how to do it :S

Comment: I have added to the original post the html from the page source, but I don't think it will clarify anything :S

Comment: Right click on table element, `inspect element` (on chrome e.g) and copy paste the HTML markup for `table` as shown in browser console. Now i better understand your expected behaviour and maybe ya `nth-child` isn't a solution for you

Comment: aaah let's see, I have add it on the original post

Comment: @eve_mf Ok let me check it

Comment: So, I guess I have to do it in another way. What about this? I have a .laborales class on css with background-color red, and another class called .festivos with background-color green.

I am trying, with jQuery to add the class .laborales, so I have to use a for loop, don't I? 

So...
var dias_totales = ($('.cadaDia').length); 
 for(var count_green = 2; count_green < dias_totales; count_green+=3) {
      $('.cadaDia').addClass('laborales');
  }

I don't have a clue about how to do it oh my God it's making me so frustrated!!!

Comment: I didn't know I could display the table only with that :o

http://jsfiddle.net/mu6v2eu2/

Comment: @eve_mf You could use a for/each loop but you could, to handle nth-child selector, just wrap all your td elements in a common parent, cloning them, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/ngk0L7zv/

Comment: wow!! it looks perfect! give me a couple of minutes that there are lots of things I've never seen!!
So this wrapAll that you've done within a div.... what does actually do? and I can't understand why do you need to wrap it :S so you are copying the class .cadaDia in the variable $clones and then wrapping it within a div, why?? Why I can't learn how you did?! :'(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92391/discussion-between-eve-mf-and-a-wolff).

Comment: The wrpper is used because `nth-child` is relative to parent so to get it working as expected, you need all your TDs to get same parent. That's said, this would be more performant using any kind of 'dummy' elements, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/ngk0L7zv/1/  This jsFiddle would be better i guess. Still the same idea, wrapping some temporary elements in a common wrapper to let us used the `:nth-child()` pseudo selector. Get the indexes of all relevant elements, then use it to target specific TDs in TABLE. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Now, using a more mathematical approach would be possible, without using any 'fake' elements but i don't have really much time currently to play with.

Comment: Here is more appropriate way using variables to handle logic in a loop: http://jsfiddle.net/c209yjme/